# I'm having trouble with mail merge field showing in Gmail or Yahoo from Salesforce Marketing Cloud. Do I need to format the data extension different?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio

I'm having trouble with mail merge field (First Name) showing up in Gmail or Yahoo when sending from Salesforce Marketing Cloud. It works fine to Outlook. Do I need to format the data extension differently?

How do I resolve this error? Thanks!

Comment: Remember to mark my answer as accepted if it has been helpful

Answer (score 1):

Mail merge (Ampscript based personalisation) is done server side, hence this is not depend on recipient’s email client. I can imagine two potential issues:

1. Less likely: your CSS causes the first name text to be hidden on some email clients
2. Most likely: first name value is not populated for all your recipients. You should check your sendable data extension for the recipient where first name is missing from the email.